# How to read a file from a java class, both are in the same jar

Tags: java, jar

I have following structure in jar

> myjar.jar -> com -> MYProgram.class
>
> ```
>        -> file.txt
> ```

In MYProgram i am trying to do:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("../file.txt")
```

I am getting NullpointerException when i try to read the inputstream..

Where is it going wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt")
```

or

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt")
```

(`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` always takes an "absolute" resource name.)

I don't believe navigating up the "directory hierarchy" works in `getResourceAsStream` - the path either has to be relative to the given class but without navigating back up the tree, or it has to be absolute to start with.

Answer (score 5):

Try the absolute path:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt")
```

The Javadoc for [`getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> - If the name begins with a '/'  ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   ```
>       modified_package_name/name
>   ```
>
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

This would turn your path into this absolute path:

```
/com/../file.txt
```

I don't think the `..` notation is respected.  It literally looks for the above absolute path.